# Error Installing imgseek on Mac Os

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install imgseek- the server version (http://www.imgseek.net/) to do image analysis.I am able to install all the dependencies successfully using:

sudo port install swig

sudo port install swig-python

sudo easy_install twisted

sudo port install imagemagick

sudo easy_install epydoc

Then I download isk-daemon from the downloads(isk-daemon-0.9.3.tar.gz) and build and install it. Everything runs succesfully.

But when I run iskdaemon.py from the command prompt, i get the following error:

sk-daemon  : WARNING  | no config file (isk-daemon.conf) found. Looked at local dir, home user dir and /etc/iskdaemon. Using defaults for everything.
root        : ERROR    Unable to load the C++ extension "_imgdb.so(pyd)" module.
root        : ERROR    See http://www.imgseek.net/isk-daemon/documents-1/compiling
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gghanakota/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/isk_daemon-0.9.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/imgSeekLib/ImageDB.py", line 35, in 
    import imgdb
  File "/Users/gghanakota/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/isk_daemon-0.9.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/imgSeekLib/imgdb.py", line 28, in 
    _imgdb = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/gghanakota/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/isk_daemon-0.9.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/imgSeekLib/imgdb.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _imgdb
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gghanakota/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/isk_daemon-0.9.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/_imgdb.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
  Referenced from: /Users/gghanakota/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/isk_daemon-0.9.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/_imgdb.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I was trying to install iskdaemon on my Mac (osx yosemite).
The problem in my case was that when I was building it, the c++ compiler threw two errors on using min function in imgdb.cpp
The error was because the types of the variables in the min function were not the same. Consequently the build failed and the imgdb module wasn't produced.
I fixed it by adding a simple typecast to the variables passed to the min function:
I changed: *min(sz, numres)* to *min(sz, (long int)numres)* on line 1003,
and *min((V.size()/2), numres)* to *min((int)(V.size()/2), numres)* on line 1327

I built again and it is working now.
Check if you get any errors when you build, maybe you are facing the same issue.